# Integration Involves Tanh, Legendre Polynomial and Gamma function

Tags: integration

Can anybody suggest me is there analytical solution exist for this integral:
$$I=\int^{+ \infty}_0 f\tanh(\pi f) |\Gamma(2k-1/2+i f)| P_{-1/2+i f}(\cosh (\tau))df$$
where  $P_a(b)$ is the Legendre Polynomail and $\Gamma()$ function.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to answer this on Physics Stack exchange and it was migrated as I did so!

This integral is an inverse  *Mehler transform* where the Gamma function and the Tanh occur naturally as poart of the normalization of the *conical functions $P_{-1/2-i\kappa}(x)$, $x\in [1,\infty]$. A Table of Mehler trabsforms appear the Bateman MS project "Tables of Integral Transforms" (Erdelyi et al eds.)

Some notes on these functions and transforms appear in my online notes http://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/hyperbolic_laplacian.pdf about page 8 or so.

Comment: thanks for this sharing but I did not see the solution in your's suggestions.